# Text box in focus when program starts

Tags: c#, textbox, focus

How can I set my text box "Fahrenheit" in focus when the program starts that I don't have to click it manually? Because the program has only 1 function and it would be more comfortable.

```
namespace Fahrenheit
{
  public partial class Form1 : Form
  {
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void label2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      this.ActiveControl = textBox1;

      double Fahrenheit = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
      double Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0;

      textBox2.Text = Celsius.ToString("F");
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
  }
}
```

Comment: you just set TabIndex=0 to that textbox you want to focus to when program start

Comment: TRY THIS >> this.ActiveControl = textBox1.Control;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the line `this.ActiveControl = textBox1;` should be below the `InitializeComponent();`  Like this:

```
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  this.ActiveControl = textBox1;
}
```

Comment: i think its better to put `this.ActiveControl = textBox1;` in form `shown` event. i havent tested yours but some times some options may not work here because form is not completely loaded.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. The main problem was that I didn't know where to put it.

Comment: The answer from jLaw also worked --> set "TabIndex=0"